# Modal popup not showing in response to button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, .net-4.6

I have searched for a solution to this problem the whole day to no avail.

I am using BS 4.0 and trying to display a modal in response to a button click, where buttons are created dynamically through Ajax call. Basically, the buttons show status of remote printers ("Ready" or an error code) and when clicked they either show printer config data or "offline.html" in an iframe inside modal.

This project is in a ASP.net, .Net 4.6, using master page. This is what I have (some changes are commented out but I left it here to show changes I made):

**CSS and JS references in Site.master file**, making sure same versions of css and js are used:

```
<%--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css") %>" />--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/jquery/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/jquery/css/jquery-ui.min.css") %>" />

<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>
<%--    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.js") %>"></script>--%>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<%--    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.json.min.js") %>"></script>--%>
```

**Modal dialog** in aspx page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="printerInfoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mainModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <span id="lblModalTitle" class="text-center"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="width:100%">
                <iframe src="" id="modeliframe" style="zoom:1.0" frameborder="0" height="550"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnCloseModal" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax code that creates button** (portion of the code, creating an "Success" button)

```
if (status == "Ready") {
    $('<div/>', { class: 'col-sm-2' }).append($('<label/>', { class: 'control-label', style: 'font-size:.8em;' }).append(document.createTextNode(' Printer ' + printer.PRINTER_NAME + ' (' + printerIP + ')')))
            .append($('<a/>', { id: 'printer' + printer.PRINTER_NAME, class: 'btn btn-success btn-block extLink', type: 'button', style: 'margin-bottom:5px;font-size:.8em;width:100%', href: printerURL, 'data-target': '#printerInfoModal', 'data-toggle': 'modal', text: status.replace(/\"/g, '') }))
            .appendTo($('#printerStatusTable'));
}
```

Where buttons are placed, in aspx file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card" id="pnlPrinterStatus">
            <div class="card-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row" id="printerStatusTable">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Markup** when I "inspect" using Chrome:

```
<div class="row" id="printerStatusTable">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label" style="font-size:.8em;"> Printer 01 (1.2.3.4)</label>
        <a id="printer01" class="btn btn-danger btn-block extLink" type="button" style="margin-bottom:5px;font-size:.8em;width:100%;color:#FFF" href="http://1.2.3.4" data-target="#printerInfoModal" data-toggle="modal">P00-No response</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label" style="font-size:.8em;"> Printer 05 (5.6.7.8)</label>
        <a id="printer05" class="btn btn-danger btn-block extLink" type="button" style="margin-bottom:5px;font-size:.8em;width:100%;color:#FFF" href="http://5.6.7.8" data-target="#printerInfoModal" data-toggle="modal">P00-No response</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I used Bootstrap 3, this worked just fine.

One additional piece of info, since I read somewhere CSS styling can mess things up too:

The "content" section of master page is in a div with class "page", which has position absolute, If I remove it it breaks the page layout and I am not a css guru (using a template for the site)

```
.page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left:200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: #F4F7FA;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.page.active {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out it is an issue with BS 4.
Excerpt from the post where I found the solution:

"class="fade in" on the modal caused it to a) be hidden and b) smoothly appear. It seems that the "in" class has now been renamed to "show"."

Solution:

```
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-backdrop .fade .in {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}


.modal-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog/issues/280) is where I found the solution: